# How can I make a tap event on a Flutter widget without actually tapping it?

Tags: flutter

How can I make a tap event on a Flutter widget without actually tapping it?

For example, how do I tap on a Button?

I know I can use`findRenderObject()` to find the widget, but then I don't know what to do.

I don't want to use `hitTest` to simulate a tap event or call the method that is assigned to a GestureDetector.onTap or RaisedButton.onPressed etc...

edit1: i want to navigator to another page and tap on a widget to show a dialog for the user

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i agree with DallaRosa - it looks like a typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: sorry for not clear enough, hope it 's ok now

Comment: so you should not "make a tap event" but rather call the code what is executed in the `onTap` callback like `showDialog()` from `material` library

Comment: so is calling the method in 'ontap' the only way to do that?

Comment: for example, you have `GestureDetector(onTap: _onTap, ...)` so the only thing you need is to call `_onTap()` - thats it, where `_onTap() {...}` is a method in your (most likely) custom `State` class